# fileio disable Rserve

Tags: r, rserve, configuration-files

I would like to prevent programs using Rserve from being able to navigate my file system, read/write files, etc. Based on the Rserve documentation on the config file, it looks like this should be possible using the "fileio disable" option:

https://www.rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html

However, I created an Rserve.cfg file as follows:

port 6312
fileio disable

and I am still able to read/write/delete files on my system through Rserve. It definitely registered the config file, as it is using port 6312, but does not give any indication of whether it registered the fileio disable option.

Does anyone know how to disable file access from Rserve? I see that the documentation isn't perfect. Is the formatting wrong?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows. Have not tried on Linux yet.

Comment: 2 years too late, but none of permission, user ID features work on Windows